# Why is the ServiceWorker not in the Navigator?

Tags: javascript, jboss, service-worker

I am attempting to incorporate ServiceWorkers into a Java EE application, but the serviceWorker is not recognized by the navigator. I've read through the other posts, researched the setup, and addressed common issues - I'm stuck on where to look next.

Webserver: JBOSS-EAP 7.0

Browser: Firefox 81.0.1

URL: localhost (HTTP)

File location: index.jsp and serviceworkers.js are both in the root WEB-INF folder

Index.jsp:

```
<script>
console.log('Attempting to register ServiceWorker...');
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
else{
    console.log('serviceWorker not in navigator');
    console.log(navigator);
}
</script>
```

serviceworker.js:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'offline-inspections-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/OfflineInspections/',
  ...
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});
```

Browser console output:

[image]

I ran a webserver using a Chrome extension using nearly this same code and it worked as expected. I've tried a variety of suggested solutions, but cannot get anything to work. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Probably because this browser don't support it: see https://caniuse.com/serviceworkers

Comment: You'll need to enable them using flags in browser settings.

Comment: Firefox 81 is supported, supposedly without needing to enable any flags. Regardless, dom.serviceWorkers.enabled = true on my browser

Comment: Oh for the love... When using localhost you have to enable the dom.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled flag (which is false by default on Firefox 81). Ridiculous. Working now. I'll post the answer once eligible, unless someone else wants to do it.

Answer (score 2):

When using localhost and Firefox, you need to enable the dom.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled flag:

1. In Firefox, go to about:config
2. Search for "dom.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled"
3. Switch the flag to TRUE

While your there, make sure dom.serviceWorkers.enabled is set to TRUE as well